# Loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

How am I not having the same results from this loop..

```
   for i in range(0,len(irradiance_list_bytes),28):
        dardy= struct.unpack("qHHHHfff",irradiance_list_bytes[i:i+28])
```

When I transform it to a list comprehension like this...

```
dardy=[struct.unpack("qHHHHfff",irradiance_list_bytes[i:i+28]) for i in range(0,len(irradiance_list_bytes),28)]
```

The result of the loop is:

```
    dardy
Out[55]: 
(631810591,
 32,
 12,
 1,
 100,
 146.53225708007812,
 -4.72298002243042,
 -7.121456623077393)
```

And the result of the list of comprehension is:

```
dardy
Out[57]: 
[(629816865,
  32,
  12,
  1,
  100,
  143.21139526367188,
  -3.786829710006714,
  -6.368762016296387),
 (630014820,
  32,
  12,
  1,
  100,
  143.46746826171875,
  -3.9606733322143555,
  -6.6814117431640625),
 (630213227,
  32,
  12,
  1,
  100,
  143.42613220214844,
  -3.992025136947632,
  -6.901387691497803),
 ......]
```

Comment: Because the *for* loop is incorrect, only storing the last iteratee value.

Comment: initialize `dardy = []` and then do `dardy.append(str...)` in the loop instead

Comment: Do you want the comprehension to work like the loop or the loop to work like the comprehension?

Comment: @Coldspeed I want to the list comprehension to work like the loop

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, No, actually the loop is working fine !

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I don't want to change the loop, I want the list comprehension to give me the same results than the loop.

Comment: @MouradOverFlow So you only need the last item in the slice?

Comment: List comprehension cannot give the same same output. It creates a *list*.

Comment: @ayhan Yeah ! It's obvious...thank you dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a list or use a *for* loop to get the last slice of items.

Use the mod operator to compute the *start index* of the last slice when the *stride* value is 28. If the list length is a factor of 28, subtract 28 from the length, otherwise subtract *length* `mod` *28* from the length:

```
l = len(irradiance_list_bytes)
dardy= struct.unpack("qHHHHfff", irradiance_list_bytes[l - (l%28 or 28):])
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the last value:

```
dardy=[struct.unpack("qHHHHfff",irradiance_list_bytes[i:i+28]) for i in range(0,len(irradiance_list_bytes),28)][-1]
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds.

Comment: Building a list when you only need a relatively small slice is pretty wasteful.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I agree with that.

Comment: Thank you sir ! It helps a lot.